# boost.random buggy warning - what does it mean?

Tags: c++, boost, random

The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost/uniform_01.html) for the uniform distribution of `boost.random` says

> Note: The current implementation is
>   buggy, because it may not fill all of
>   the mantissa with random bits. I'm
>   unsure how to fill a (to-be-invented)
>   boost::bigfloat class with random bits
>   efficiently. It's probably time for a
>   traits class.

I have no idea what this means (what is the mantissa?).  Does it mean that I shouldn't use the distribution (in which case why is it in the relase package?)? or is that I should just be careful (not to do what?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a warning that the current `boost::random` implementation doesn't fill all of the bits with the same distribution, so the numbers are "slightly less random" (have fun quantifying that statement) than they could have been.

Chances are, however, that you won't be able to tell anyway.

Comment: Thanks, Is it talking about the precision of the number?  Will there, say, be some correlations at very high precision? but at lower precision it is fine? I don't need my number to be random to 16 decimal places, but I do need it to be random to, say, 4 dp?

Comment: @Tom, precision is a weird thing to try to quantify for numbers that by definition are supposed to have 0 precision (ie are random).

Comment: It does make sense to discuss the random-ness of parts of a random number. Famously, the low bit of old `rand()` implementations was not random at all. That's equivalent to saying that the expression `rand() % 2` is not random at all.

Comment: @Tom: The mantissa is (by definition) not involved with decimal places. So, even your 16 decimal places will be perfectly fine (assuimg that you use a FP type that can hold them). The issue is that `1.2345678E-64` should be 10 times less likely as  `1.2345678E-63`, but isn't. (But uniform distributions are notoriously tricky for FP anyway).

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, the Java documentation for java.util.Random discusses the current implementation and a previous implementation for [nextFloat and nextDouble](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextFloat%28%29), discussing how it can be tricky getting the randomness right for these methods.